# I had not seen your message yesterday. I did not purposely delay my reply

Tags: sentence-construction

A friend sent me a good morning text.I saw the message in the afternoon and replied then as good afternoon.She did not text me back.How to tell her in the next day that I did not purposely delay replying to her. I just did not see her message at that time

Answer (score 1):

### Use the simple and continuous past tenses

> Sorry! I **didn't see** your message yesterday morning until later that day. I **wasn't avoiding** replying.

Reason: your not seeing the message happened, once and completely, in the past (simple).

You then refer to the period of time between when the message arrived and when you finally did send a reply. During that time, you were (not) continually avoiding replying.

Lastly, "replying" is a gerund and therefore uses -ing.